# Don't open activity if already open when clicking notifications

Tags: android, parsing, push

How can I force the app to **not** open a new activity if it's already opened?
Using **Parse** `ParsePush` with a `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.

```
@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (App.isRunning) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // open app
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the answer if yes than share with me, i am also facing the same issue in my application...

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way is launchMode="singleInstance" in your manifest, since launching from a notification creates a new Task.

Comment: Beware of unintended consequences when you use singleInstance. The developer docs say "SingleTop is also a common and useful launch mode for many types of activities. The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications."

Comment: This did not work. I don't want to mess with the activities and their modes, I practically want to override the `startActivity` that is in the code I'm not able to reach.

Comment: I know singletask is dangerous and I don't recommend it. I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you just want to prevent the Activity from opening while it's currently shown on screen, you can just set a static flag when that Activity is started and clear it when the Activity is stopped. If the flag is set, don't call startActivity().

Comment: Also, it is generally a bad idea to directly open an Activity in response to a push message without any user interaction, if that's what you're doing.